# setup MoreViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

OK, I'm a sinner.
The good news is: I use multiple Storyboards (yay!)
The bad news: I'm not inspired enough to escape the 'More..' tab.

Now:
I need to make the moreviewcontroller to look like the rest of my app.

So, in my

> AppDelegate

I do:

```
let tabController = UITabBarController()
```

and in my

> didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

I do:

```
self.tabController.moreNavigationController.topViewController?.view.tintColor = .red
self.tabController.moreNavigationController.navigationBar.topItem?.title = "MyString"
self.tabController.moreNavigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = .red
```

When I launch my app, none of the above is visible, nor is any error logged in the console

My assumption is, that I refer to the wrong tabbarcontroller, and maybe that could be explained by the fact that I have multiple Storyboards?

Help!

Comment: where you init **tabController** var ??

Comment: in my appedelegate

Comment: @Sh_Khan: OK, you got a point. IN disfinishLaunching.. I had to do tabBarController = self.window?.rootViewController as! UITabBarController

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your edits are in

```
let tabController = UITabBarController()
```

that has no relation to the real tab then it's on the fly so you need to either init it then assign it to the window root or if you use storyboard access it with

```
if let tab = self.window?.rootViewController as? UITabBarController {
  // do whatever you want 
}
```